# How to shift elements to left after removing array element?

Tags: java, arrays, element

I was asked to write, to remove the element `(lets say k=30)` from the array and shift the other elements to its left without using inbuilt methods.

I have tried the below approach.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 30, 4, 5, 30, 6 };

    int k = 30;
    int count = 0;

    System.out.println("---Original Array------");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        if (arr[i] == k)
            count++;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

            if (arr[i] == k) {
                for (int l = i; l < arr.length - 1; l++) {
                    arr[l] = arr[l + 1];
                }
            }
        }

    }

    System.out.println("---Modified Array------");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }

}
```

I need output like this: `[1 2 4 5 6 0 0]`

But the output from the above logic is: `[1 2 4 5 6 6 6]`

Also, I'm worried about using nested for loops here. Is there any way that we can reduce the time complexity with out using any inbuilt methods?

Comment: A `break` is missing somewhere . :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another variant:

```
    int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 30, 4, 5, 30, 6 };

    int k = 30;
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != k) {
            arr[j++] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    while (j < arr.length) {
        arr[j++] = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to not change your approach drastically, I would suggest adding another iteration of the array at the end, to insert `0`s to `count`-many indices from the end of your array.

This would be as simple as adding the following snippet:

```
// nested for loop
// ...

// set trailing elements to 0s
for (int i = 0; i < count ; i++) 
    arr[arr.length-1-i] = 0;

System.out.println("\n---Modified Array------");
// ...
```

There are some cleaner/more-efficient ways of solving this problem. 
Based exactly on your approach, I went ahead and made a modification to your nested loop to not require another iteration.

```
for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == k) {
            for (int l = i; l < arr.length - 1; l++)
                arr[l] = arr[l + 1];
            // since we have performed the shifting, we can safely set the last element to 0
            arr[arr.length-1] = 0;   // <----- this was missing!!
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code gives the desired result:

```
int [] arr = { 1, 2, 30, 4, 5, 30, 6 };
int k = 30;

int elementCount = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == k) {
        ++elementCount;
    }
}

int count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == k) {
        count++;
        for (int j = i; j < arr.length-1; j++) {
            arr[j] = arr[j+1];
        }
        arr[arr.length-1] = 0;
    }

    if (count == elementCount) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it helps. This is a simplified aproach, that is easier to read and understand(at least for people that learned C), that does removal as required....

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 30, 4, 5, 30, 6 };
        int k = 30;
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        for(;j<arr.length;i++,j++){
            if((arr[i]=arr[j])==k) i--;
        }
        while(i<j)arr[i++]=0;
        System.err.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
   }
```

output:[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0]

Answer (score 0):

First version with a small fix on your code. You issue is that the shifted elements need to be replaced by zero. Which require basically an if statement with the `arr.length - count`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 30, 4, 5, 30, 6 };

        int k = 30;
        int count = 0;

        System.out.println("---Original Array------");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

            if (arr[i] == k)
                count++;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if(i >= arr.length - count){
                    arr[i] = 0;
                }else {
                    if (arr[i] == k) {
                        for (int l = i; l < arr.length - 1; l++) {
                            arr[l] = arr[l + 1];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        System.out.println("---Modified Array------");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");

    }
```

Which gives output

```
---Original Array------
1 2 30 4 5 30 6 
---Modified Array------
1 2 4 5 6 0 0
```

Now, we can simplify the code also

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 30, 4, 5, 30, 6 };
        int k = 30;
        int count = 0;

        System.out.println("---Original Array------");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");


        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            if(arr[i]==k){
                count++;
            }else{
                arr[i-count] = arr[i];
            }
        }

        for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++){
            arr[arr.length - i] = 0;
        }

        System.out.println("---Modified Array------");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

which give the same output